# Send email with attachement via php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, phpmailer

What is wrong with my code ?

Email with out attachment works, but with attachment dont work :(

I tried on milion option but still not work. I think, that something is wrong with header , ttha cant be send with attachment.

Could someone help me with this problem? I've already lost several hours and unfortunately I can't solve this problem myself.

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "xxxx@icloud.com";
    $from_email     = "noreply@xxx.pl";
     
    $subject    = "subject";
    $cnc        = $_POST["cnc_wheels"];
    $pain       = $_POST["new_paint_wheels"];
   
    $message_body = "email data";

    $file_attached = false;
    if(isset($_FILES["font_img_wheels"])) {
        $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['font_img_wheels']['tmp_name'];
        $file_name        = $_FILES['font_img_wheels']['name'];
        $file_size        = $_FILES['font_img_wheels']['size'];
        $file_type        = $_FILES['font_img_wheels']['type'];
        $file_error       = $_FILES['font_img_wheels']['error'];

        if($file_error>0) {
            $mymsg = array( 
            1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini", 
            2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 
            3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 
            4=>"No file was uploaded", 
            6=>"Missing a temporary folder" ); 
            
            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => $mymsg[$file_error]));
            die($output); 
        }
        
        $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
        $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        $file_attached = true;
    }
    
    if($file_attached) {
         # Mail headers should work with most clients
         $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
         $headers = "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n";
         $headers .= "From: ".$from_email."\r\n";
         $headers .= "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n";
         $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email_client"]."" . "\r\n";
         $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".md5('boundary1')."\r\n\r\n";
         
         $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
         $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;  boundary=".md5('boundary2')."\r\n\r\n";
         
         $headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."\r\n";
         $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
         $headers .= $message_body."\r\n\r\n";
         
         $headers .= "--".md5('boundary2')."--\r\n";
         $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."\r\n";
         $headers .= "Content-Type:  ".$file_type."; ";
         $headers .= "name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
         $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
         $headers .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
         $headers .= "filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
         $headers .= "X-Attachment-Id:".rand(1000,9000)."\r\n\r\n";
         $headers .= $encoded_content."\r\n";
         $headers .= "--".md5('boundary1')."--";
    }else{
        $headers = 'From: '.$_POST["email_client"].'' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: '.$_POST["email_client"].'' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    }
   
    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Wiadomość nie została wysłana.'));
        die($output);
    }else {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Dziękujemy, za zapytanie. Skontaktujemy się niebawem.'));
        die($output);
    }
}
```

I expecting, that some one can help me.

Solved by below code

$boundary = md5(time());

```
$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $boundary . "\"\r\n";

$body = "--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
$body .= $message . "\r\n";

if ($_FILES["font_img_wheels"]["size"] > 0) {
    $attachment_name = $_FILES["font_img_wheels"]["name"];
    $attachment_tmp_name = $_FILES["font_img_wheels"]["tmp_name"];
    $attachment_data = file_get_contents($attachment_tmp_name);
    $attachment_encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment_data));

    $body .= "--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $attachment_name . "\"\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= $attachment_encoded . "\r\n";
}

if ($_FILES["second_img_wheels"]["size"] > 0) {
    $attachment_name = $_FILES["second_img_wheels"]["name"];
    $attachment_tmp_name = $_FILES["second_img_wheels"]["tmp_name"];
    $attachment_data = file_get_contents($attachment_tmp_name);
    $attachment_encoded = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment_data));

    $body .= "--" . $boundary . "\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $attachment_name . "\"\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= $attachment_encoded . "\r\n";
}

$body .= "--" . $boundary . "--";

if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Dziękujemy, za zapytanie. Skontaktujemy się niebawem.'));
    die($output);
}else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Wiadomość nie została wysłana.'));
    die($output);
}
```

Comment: You've tagged `phpmailer` but you're not using it in your code. Perhaps you should. It's a whole lot easier than trying to craft a multi-part attachment yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few small adjustments to your `if($file_attached)` block. I've added comments inline describing the changes.

```
if($file_attached) {
    // initialize boundary variables
    $boundary1 = md5('boundary1');
    $boundary2 = md5('boundary2');

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()."\r\n"; // changed from = to .=
    $headers .= "From: ".$from_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Subject: ".$subject."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email_client"]."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".$boundary1."\r\n\r\n";

    // use the $body variable to construct the email content
    // the attachment will now be included in the body of the email
    $body = "--".$boundary1."\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=".$boundary2."\r\n\r\n";

    $body .= "--".$boundary2."\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= $message_body."\r\n\r\n";

    $body .= "--".$boundary2."--\r\n";
    $body .= "--".$boundary1."\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: ".$file_type."; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
    $body .= "X-Attachment-Id:".rand(1000,9000)."\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= $encoded_content."\r\n";
    $body .= "--".$boundary1."--";
    
    // adjusted to match $body and send email within this block
    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
```

It's also possible there are restrictions on sending or receiving the file via email depending on how large the attachment is.

If this is the case, in your `php.ini` file you should adjust the following to fit your needs:

- `upload_max_filesize` - Specifies the maximum size of an uploaded file. It should be set to a value greater than your attachment
- `post_max_size` - Limits the size of POST data. This value must be larger than `upload_max_filesize`
- `memory_limit` - Sets the maximum amount of memory that a script is allowed to allocate. It should be higher than the file size you are processing

Apache's `LimitRequestBody` may also be interfering.

It's important to note that the issue may also be on the *receiving* end. Some email clients won't accept incoming emails where their size is past a certain threshold.

Comment: Ok, so how to set up for example 3MB per file ?

Comment: `upload_max_filesize = 5M`, `post_max_size = 7M`, `memory_limit = 128M`